# How to remove extra parameters from powershell output

Tags: powershell

I have below script to fetch all users in a domain and their group membership. In the output if you see I have group names but they are in the format of CN, i want to format the output and just get group names.

```
Get-ADUser -Server "dc.domain.com" -Properties * | select-object -property Name,samAccountName,@{N="MemberOf";E={$_.MemberOf -join ","}},@{N="PrimaryGroup";E={$_.PrimaryGroup -join ","}} | export-csv C:\Temp\userdetails.csv    


"Name","samAccountName","MemberOf","PrimaryGroup"
 "Administrator","Administrator","CN=Group Policy Creator Owners,CN=Users,DC=SMSNOW,DC=COM,CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=SMSNOW,DC=COM,CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=SMSNOW,DC=COM","CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=SMSNOW,DC=COM"
```

To be clear I want output like

```
"Name","samAccountName","MemberOf","PrimaryGroup"
"Administrator","Administrator","Group Policy Creator Owners,Users,Domain Admins,Users,Administrators,Builtin,","Domain Users,Users"
```

Help is very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not say what version of PoSH you are on, but is all you want use Groups and members,

Try this...

```
# Get all AD groups and the members
 ForEach ($GroupName in (Get-ADGroup -Filter *))
 {
 "The AD Group $GroupName.Name members are:"
 Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName.Name | Select Name
 "`n"
 }
```

Results...

```
The AD Group CN=WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__,CN=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com Name members are:

The AD Group CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=contoso,DC=com Name members are:

Name
----
Domain Admins
Enterprise Admins
Administrator

The AD Group CN=Users,CN=Builtin,DC=contoso,DC=com Name members are:

Name
----                                          
Domain Users
Authenticated Users
INTERACTIVE
Labadmin
...
```

Depending on you PoSH version you could just use this...

```
# Get users and their groups memberships
 (Get-ADUser -Filter *) | % {
 "`nThe user " + $_.SamAccountName + ', is in the following AD Groups: '
 Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_.SamAccountName |
 Select Name,GroupCategory,GroupScope } |
 Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Results ...

```
The user Administrator, is in the following AD Groups: 

Name                                   GroupCategory  GroupScope
----                                   -------------  ----------
Domain Users                                Security      Global
Administrators                              Security DomainLocal
Schema Admins                               Security   Universal
Enterprise Admins                           Security   Universal
Domain Admins                               Security      Global
...

The user Guest, is in the following AD Groups: 
Domain Guests                               Security      Global
Guests                                      Security DomainLocal

The user krbtgt, is in the following AD Groups: 
Domain Users                                Security      Global
Denied RODC Password Replication Group      Security DomainLocal
...
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the answer short: You can extend your calculated property with a foreach loop to extract each single group name like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Server "dc.domain.com" -Properties * | 
    Select-Object -Property Name,samAccountName,@{Name="MemberOf";Expression={$_.MemberOf | ForEach-Object {Get-ADGroup -Identity $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name}}},@{Name="PrimaryGroup";Expression={$_.PrimaryGroup -join ","}} | 
        Export-Csv  -Path C:\Temp\userdetails.csv
```